# Why Tensorboard1.15 creates a separate plot per each global_step?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a class that creates a writer when initialized:

```
self.sess = tf.Session()
self.summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(train_log_dir)
```

Then, in another function, I run

```
with tf.name_scope('stats'):
    for i in range(num_epochs):
        tf.summary.scalar("some_parameter", val1)
        summaries = tf.summary.merge_all()
        summary = self.sess.run(summaries)
        self.summary_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
        self.summary_writer.flush()
```

In tensorboard, I expect to have one plot where I see some_parameter values per each i. Instead, I see num_epochs plots, each named as `stats_i/some_parameter`, where i is a number of an epoch.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently, I was missing `tf.reset_default_graph()` in the initializer. Although this solved my problem, if anyone can explain such behavior, I would appreciate.

Comment: Additionally, I need to call `tf.summary.scalar` only once outside the loop, "link" it to some variable, and change the variable. Also, `tf.reset_default_graph()` should go before `tf.Session()`, otherwise I get `Session graph is empty` error, for also unknown to me reason.